# Reading a 1-dimensional Matlab array built on pairwise interactions

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a bunch of data with labels [0-9]. I want to gather information based on all the pairwise interactions of these data. To avoid redundancy, I do something like this:

```
a = zeros(45, 1);
pair = 1;
for i = 1:9
  for j = (i+1):10
    a(pair) = i * j;
    pair = pair + 1;
  end
end
```

If I want to examine everything in `a` I can loop through it in a 2-dimensional way using the `pair`, `i`, `j` structure. That's fine. But what if I want to programmatically examine only **certain** pairs? Is there some logic by which I can do something analogous to `a(i,j)`, where a(i,j) is actually "the coefficients from the model that was trained on data classes `i` and `j`"?

Running Matlab_R2018b. For the curious, I'm doing this as part of a [DAGSVM](http://vllab.ucmerced.edu/nakul/ImprovMult.pdf) implementation.

Comment: you have a 1-d array. I'm not clear on what you want to do with something analogous to `a(i,j)`. What is your expected result?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question properly, I'd implement it as a [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) matrix. You'd access it like a full matrix `a(i,j)`, but only the pairs you specify are actually stored in memory.

Comment: @ShadowMan it's a 1-d array but its entries represent two inputs, if that makes sense. So the expected output of `a(i,j)` is actually `"the coefficients from the model that was trained on data classes i and j"`. Does that make sense?

Comment: But if your question is about indexing, I think we need to know more about how you determine which pairs you're going to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the input information along side the resulting vector.

```
a = zeros(45, 1);
pair = 1;
I = a;
J = a;
for i = 1:9
  for j = (i+1):10
    I(pair) = i;
    J(pair) =j;
    a(pair) = i * j;
    pair = pair + 1;
  end
end
res=[a,I,J];
```

Then using a function match the input values to a given pair using a tolerance for floating point values.

```
function Val = findVal(res,pair)
  #pair = [i,j]
  pairs = res(:,2:3);
  ind = sum(abs(pairs-pair)<1e-6,2)==2;
  if sum(ind) == 0
    disp('No match found')
    Val = NaN
  else    
    Val = res(ind,1);
    disp('pair')
    disp(pair)
    disp('value')
    disp(Val)
  end
endfunction
```

Now I generate two pairs, one that is in the set and the other that is not to show the usage of the function.

```
testpair = res(8,2:3)
badpair = [20,20]
findVal(res,testpair)
findVal(res,badpair)
```

Comment: Forgot to comment at the time, but this is more or less what worked.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need loops for this. 
If `i` spans the range `[1:I]` and `j` spans the range `[1:J]`, then you have `K = I*J` possible interactions half of which are redundant/permutations `(A(i,j) = A(j,i))`.

```
j = mod(pair, J); % "row"
i = floor((pair-1) / J) + 1; % "col"
pair = j + i * J; % linear index
```

To access only certain combinations you can just use this basic linear indexing.

`a(pair) = a(j,i) = a(i,j) = i * j`;

It sounds like you'd like to avoid self interaction & redundancy so only choose pairs where either `i > j` xor `j > i` which is equivalent to just creating either the upper triangular or lower triangular (as in your code above) matrix.